# Spring, Need to use a a bean declared in a ApplicationContextFactory servlet, in a DispatcherServlet

Tags: spring

i have a web.xml with these 2 servlet:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>ApplicationContextFactory</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.bamboo.common.factory.ApplicationContextFactory</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

AND

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

I need to use these bean declared on the ApplicationContextFactory:

```
 <bean id="**catalogFacadeTarget**" class="com.bamboo.catW3.business.impl.CatalogFacadeImpl">
        <property name="categoryDAO"><ref local="categoryDAOTarget"/></property>
        <property name="containerDAO"><ref local="containerDAOTarget"/></property>
        <property name="productDAO"><ref local="productDAOTarget"/></property>
        <property name="productOptionDAO"><ref local="productOptionDAOTarget"/></property>
        <property name="productStatusDAO"><ref local="productStatusDAOTarget"/></property>
        <property name="userDAO"><ref local="userDAOTarget"/></property>
</bean>
```

in the dispatcher-servlet like this:

```
<bean name="welcome"
    class="com.bamboo.catW3.business.impl.Welcome">
    <property name="successView">
        <value>welcome</value>
    </property>
     <property name="catalogFacadeImpl"><ref   local="**categoryDAOTarget**"/> </property>
</bean>
```

Is it posible some how? Thank you!

Comment: So you need to be able to use dependency-injection in your servlets, right?

Comment: hello Bozho, i don´t know what dependecy injection means!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't share contexts between servlets.

If you need to share beans, then you need to move the shared beans out of the `ApplicationContextFactory` servlet's context and into the root webapp context, using a `ContextLoaderListener` declared in `web.xml`. Both servlets will then be able to use the beans defined in that root context.

(I'd give you a link, but springsource.org seems be down at the moment).

Comment: At least i have a direction thank you! how about that link, springsource.org seems to be up